# How do I add two different event listeners to one button

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to make two different function be trigger by one button. So far I have try to just adding the second eventlistener as the // part but it didn't work, the two function should be executed one after the other. 
I am just staring with javascript. sorry if this question seems a little to easy, but I can't figure if out. I have try creating a function call it function0 and call the function1 and function2, but it doesn't seem to work either. thanks!!!

```
var action= document.getElementById("click1");
action.addEventListener("click",function1,false);

//action.addEventListener("click", function2, false);


<!-- click1 button -->
<button id="click1" value = "first"></button><br>
```

Comment: why dont you just call your second function from inside of function1?

Comment: Why not make the click fire `functiona` and have functiona call function1 and function2

Comment: That code should work just fine in the manner you've described, assuming you have actually defined both functions.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/2woype10/)

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are doing it ok, you can use subsequent calls to `addEventListner`. Probably you have a syntax error in one of your callbacks functions (`function1` or `function2`), check out this code:

```
var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Listener 1');
});

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('Listener 2');
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://codepen.io/ianaya89/pen/mJBGog)